# How can I initialize a static const vector that is a class member in c++11?

Tags: c++, class, vector, c++11, initialization

I need to initialize a static const vector that is a class member.

I have tried:

```
static const vector<string> vr ({"2", "3", "4"});  

static const vector<string> vr = {"2", "3", "4"}; 

static const vector<string> vr {"2", "3", "4"};
```

However, none of these work.

I am using Eclipse with mingw. (I have enabled c++11)

Comment: defined static variables inside class and do assignment outside-

Answer (score 20):

Static variable initialization is done outside of the class, like this:

```
class Example
{
    static const vector<string> vr;
    // ...
};

const vector<string> Example :: vr ({"hello", "world"});
```

Comment: Is there any way to initialize a `const` `vector` with a `static` member function?

Answer (score 13):

Declare your static members in your class definition, but define them outside.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    // declaration
    static const std::vector<std::string> vec;
};

// definition
const std::vector<std::string> MyClass::vec = ...;
```

The exception to this is integral types,

```
class MyClass {
public:
    // declaration and definition
    static const int MAX_BURRITOS = 5;
};
```

Comment: The exception for integral types only applies if the values are never ODR-used.

Answer (score 10):

You did limit your question to C++11 but I will drop this here for future visitors who find this in search results.

If you're able to move forward to **C++17**, you can use `const static inline` to initialize the static member within the class declaration and no longer need to have it outside the class.

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Test {
public:
    const static inline std::vector<std::string> Names = { "Fred", "Barney", "Wilma" };
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Test::Names[0];
    return 0;
}
```